# Swiftui Background (Material vs systemColor)

Tags: swift, swiftui

Can someone tell me why those are working:

```swift
.background(.regularMaterial)
.background(Color(.systemGray5))
```

But it's not working like this?

```swift
.background(colorScheme == .dark ? .regularMaterial : Color(.systemGray5))
```

Comment: Define "not working". Compiler error? Runtime error? Unexpected behavior (clearly describe what you want and what you are seeing)?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is an [overload](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/view/background(_:ignoressafeareaedges:)) of `background` that takes a `ShapeStyle`, which both `Material.regularMaterial` and `Color` conform to.

However, the problem is that the 2 sides of the ternary operator must always have the same type - you cannot have `Material` on one side and `Color` on the other side, even though both conform to the same protocol.

You can however create your own `@ViewBuilder` method, which conditionally calls `background` with the appropriate value. This way you are always calling `background` with a concrete type.

```
extension View {
  @ViewBuilder
  func myBackground(colorScheme: ColorScheme) -> some View {
    if colorScheme == .dark {
      background(.regularMaterial)
    } else {
      background(Color(.systemGray))
    }
  }
}
```

Then just call `myBackground` in your View.

```
struct ViewWithBackground: View {
  @Environment var colorScheme: ColorScheme

  var body: some View {
    Text("Body")
      .myBackground(colorScheme: colorScheme)
  }
}
```

Comment: thank you for that detailed description!

Answer (score 0):

I prefer to use the generic type-erased style as mentioned [here.](https://forums.swift.org/t/ultrathinmaterial-doesnt-work-in-ternary-operator/65084/2)

`.background(conditionToCheck ? AnyShapeStyle(Color.yourColor) : AnyShapeStyle(.yourMaterial))`